# How do I get the Find Bar back in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I have somehow broken the find bar in Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 8.1

When I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, I get this dialog box

[image: Find Dialog Box in IE11]

If I go through the menus (Edit → Find) then I get nothing at all.

Is this some setting I've accidentally changed? And if so, how do I change it back?

If not, then how on earth have I broken it?

Comment: What happens if you drag the title bar to the location it came from? Does it snap back at all?

Comment: @Burgi Nice idea, but no. It's behaving like a dialog box, not a floating toolbar (ie it's modal).

Comment: I have to say I am stumped... struggling to even Google the problem. Is the PC on a domain? I am wondering if it is some crazy group policy thing.

Comment: @Burgi It is on a domain, but other PCs on the domain are fine and I asked the GPO admin and it's not him. And if I'd found anything useful in the hour I spent on Google, I wouldn't have asked here...

Comment: When I mentioned Google I was referring to the fact searching for "floating" and "IE11" returns loads of pages on CSS. This [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2008/12/10/new-accessibility-features-in-ie8/) seems to suggest it is some sort of compatibility mode.

Comment: I only can think of 4 things: 1) make sure you don't have any activeX plugins, etc messing with it. 2) clear all settings as suggested in the answer. 3) find IE settings in the registry and see if anything looks suspicious. 4) switch to a good web browser (not to put too fine a point on it).

Comment: @Wyatt8740 I'm posting this from Firefox - but our finance application at work only works in IE, so I have to use it occasionally.  Problem was when I was searching for an invoice...

Comment: @RichardGadsden Ah, sorry to hear that. IE is pretty much my least favorite part of Windows, because it's impossible to dive in and find out why something isn't working right (as opposed to FF/chrome or my favorite seamonkey). I'll flip through the settings I know of though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what would cause this issue but resetting everything IE-related should do the trick unless this is to do with PC policy (as Burgi says) or MS updates.

To reset all the IE preferences (**note that this will erase all bookmarks, preferences, history, cookies, passwords, etc stored in IE**):

1. Open Internet Explorer.
2. Click the Settings icon in the upper-right-hand corner.
3. Click `Internet Options`.
4. Click on the `Advanced` tab.
5. Click `Reset`.
6. Click `Reset` and let the process finish.

If this still fails then you may want to 'reinstall' Internet Explorer, as [this Microsoft help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/318378) details. Essentially, on Windows 8.1, you want to disable IE, reboot and enable IE. You can also use the System File Checker tool.

Comment: This seems to be a bit of a nuclear option

Comment: Indeed. Not sure what else to suggest as I don't know the cause of the issue.

Comment: I did it without checking the Delete personal settings box and it worked.  Definitely a nuclear option, as it required a reboot, but at least I still have my favorites.

Comment: Glad it worked. Probably a better way to have fixed the issue. I've edited my answer to exclude the deletion of personal settings.